# How to create multiple line-breaks in a dynamic image when needed?

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation

Currently I've got the following working just fine without any problems (yet).

```
header ("Content-type: image/png");

$string = $_REQUEST['text'];
$font = 15;

$width = 300;
$height = 350;
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

$back = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$border = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

ImageFilledRectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $border);
ImageFilledRectangle($image, 1, 1, $width-2, $height-2, $back);

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);

ImageStringWrap($image, $font, 3, 2, $string, $text_color, $width-2 );

imagepng($image);

function ImageStringWrap($image, $font, $x, $y, $text, $color, $maxwidth) {
    $fontwidth = ImageFontWidth($font);
    $fontheight = ImageFontHeight($font);

    if ($maxwidth != NULL) {
        $maxcharsperline = floor($maxwidth / $fontwidth);
        $text = wordwrap($text, $maxcharsperline, "\n", false);
    }

    while (list($numl, $line) = each($lines)) {
        ImageString($image, $font, $x, $y, $line, $color);
        $y += $fontheight;
    }
}
```

While the above works great, one thing I've been failing to work is be able to get line breaks like would come out akin to `nl2br()`.

The text that this is pulling from in `$_REQUEST['text']` is from the database, which was originally inserted from a textarea and passed to this script via URL. Naturally when people type in a textarea, there are line breaks that come from that. While printing it to the browser via text is easy, I can't seem to get the same result within an image.

I haven't spend a long time working with the GD library, but after searching around I really can't find anything about how to do this. Is it just not possible?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but can you use ImageMagick? It can do it out of the box: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label_lines

Comment: What I have working does multiple lines. If I type something, it will auto-wrap the text in the image and create a wall of text--that's fine. My only issue is not being able to break that wall of text into paragraphs where needed on that image and I can't seem to figure a way how. Can ImageMagick do that?

From what I see there, it seems to do what I have above out of the box, but still not do the paragraph breaking (at least in those examples).

Comment: I have similar que. How to line break in dynamic generated image.